# 'this' operator has a error in my code. 'The expression must have a class type'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, syntax-error, this

```cpp
class Person {
    string name;
    int age;
    Person();
    Person(string n, int a) {
        this.name = n;
        this.age = a;
    }
};
```

I wrote this code in visual studio, but I met an error message
'식에 클래스 형식이 있어야 합니다.' in English  'The expression must have a class type. ' (I'm not sure that It is the correct translation)

How do I fix it?

Comment: `this` is a pointer, so you have to write `this->` (which any decent C++ book should tell you)

Comment: English is the only acceptable language.

Comment: If you can speak English, I highly recommend you to switch the language of your IDE into English.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation :) I will switch my main language of my IDE into English !

Answer (score 3):

`this` is not an operator. `.` is the member access operator, but as `this` is a pointer you need the `->` operator (dereference and member access):

```
Person(string n, int a) {
    this->name = n;
    this->age = a;
}
```

However, you shouldn't use `this` here at all, but rather initialize members in the member initializer list:

```
Person(string n, int a) : name(n),age(a) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

`this` is a pointer to the current object. If you want to refer to its members (both data members or methods), you need to use the `->` operator:

```
Person(string n, int a) {
    this->name = n;
    this->age = a;
}
```